# what does the following snippet mean

Tags: python, django, django-models

I am a python django newbie, and was going through some open source code, What does the following source code mean:

this was inside models.py of a django application.

```
class Sale(models.Model):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(Sale, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```

Please keep your language simple. I am a non computer science background and new to OOP.

Comment: You'd need to provide more for this to have any deeper meaning.  When `__init__` **only** contains this kind of `super` construct, it doesn't actually do anything interesting, since that's effectively the default behavior of a class.  Was there more code?  If so, can you provide a hint as to what's in it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Define a class `Sale` which is a subclass of `models.Model`
2. Define an initializer for `Sale` which takes any number of positional arguments (`*args`) and any keyword arguments (`**kwargs`)
3. That initializer will invoke the initializer of the superclass (`super(Sale, self).__init__`) passing along all of the positional and keyword arguments it received.

Basically it "passes through" arguments to its initializer to the parent class's initializer .

Comment: Note that this is basically the same as not defining `__init__` in `Sale`, unless there are other statements after the `super` call.

Comment: Yep. Pretty redundant unless there's other stuff in the constructor.

Comment: Quibble: `__init__` is not a constructor, it's an initializer. The object is fully constructed before calling `__init__`.

Comment: @DanielRoseman - legit. I'll edit it. (For most intents and purposes, no one cares, and C/C++ use constructors to mean initializers a lot of the time, but you're right.)

Comment: An answer may be: "This is a template to modify class constructor". Write code after or before `super` to modify behavior. What do you think about this?